# MessageInputBar disappear after tapping the input bar

Tags: ios, swift, messagekit

Please note that I use this project in my swift app:

https://github.com/instamobile/messenger-iOS-chat-swift-firestore

I have tried to include chat in my running app. When I tap the input bar it disappears. I test the same code in the new swift app with the same pod. It works fine but when I put it in my old app the `MessageInputBar` disappear after tapping the input bar.

```
version of MessageKit : 2.0.0
version of iOS : 12
version of Swift : 4.2
```

Comment: format and correct

Answer (score 0):

the reason is DAKeyboardControl.h (Plug in)
it works after comment the following line
//method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);